# Combining Pinax and REST framework in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-socialauth, pinax

I am making a mobile app for social networking. On the backend I am using Django because it comes with various packages like PINAX and REST framework

I can understand PINAX separately, it creates a social network instantly. However, I do not need a web-based social network, but need to produce REST APIs like www.mysite.com/feed -- where user can Create, Read, Delete or Update feeds (just like they would do on the website). I am not sure how to use REST framework in this respect - do I need to change teh source code in PINAX files, or is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Your question confuses me a little, I think you are asking how to use Pinax but with a REST framework?
I recently used Pinax and the Django REST API as a backend for a mobile app, we used the models etc. from Pinax but implemented all our views in the REST framework instead of creating standard views. It was all fairly straight forward once we got into it.
It also means to you can create HTML views for debugging, which is really handy.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, how to substitute the standard HTML views in Pinax with REST API views. Is your code, or parts of it on github? Or if you can share them with you, it would be really useful for my learning purpose. Thanks a lot